# ng2-ckeditor Add Placeholder plugin using typescript and angular 2.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, ckeditor

I am trying to get placeholder plugin in the CKEditor toolbar but getting following error when adding `extraPlugins:'placeholder'` to CKEditor config -

```
Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "placeholder" was not found at "//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/plugins/placeholder/plugin.js?t=G6DD".
```

Here is console log screenshot - 
[image]

I have also created a [**plunker**](https://embed.plnkr.co/qTfZxG/).

I have installed **"ng2-ckeditor": "^1.0.4"** via npm.

Can i get some help ?

Answer (score 1):

you should use that:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and you should use in your CKEdior tag:

```
<ckeditor
  [(ngModel)]="sampleContent"
  [config]="{uiColor: '#a0a0a0',extraPlugins:'placeholder'}"
  debounce="500">
</ckeditor>
```

and you can use :

```
(change)="onChange($event)"
```

but you must define in your Component:

```
onChange(body:any) {
 //your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following If you want to use placeholder or other plugins

**1-** go to this page (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/plugins/all) and download your plugin(like placeholder) and place it in the assets folder of your project

**2-** include **ckeditor** from a CDN **(in the index.html)**

```
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.12.1/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

**3-** reference the placeholder plugin **(in the index.html)**

```
  <script src="./assets/ckediotr/plugins/placeholder/plugin.js"></script>
```

Now, it's time to use it

in the app.component :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ckeditorContent = 'angualrckeditor';
  ngOnInit(): void {
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (event, data) {
      var editor = event.editor,
        element = editor.element;
      editor.name = "content"
    });
  }
}
```

in the app.component.html

```
<form #form="ngForm">
 <ckeditor #myEditor [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent" name="ckeditorContent"
  [config]="{uiColor: '#a4a4a4' , allowedContent: false,forcePasteAsPlainText: false , extraPlugins: 'placeholder'}"
  debounce="500"> </ckeditor>
</form>
```