# How to add plugins to ng2-ckeditor using TypeScript and Angular 2 ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ckeditor

I'm trying to add the **Justify** plugin to my ckeditor, but unfortunately I can't find any information about how I should add plugins to ng2-ckeditor.

Also I'm not able to find any directory or config file where I should add plugins.

I'm using ng2-ckeditor **1.0.6** with TypeScript.

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208766/ng2-ckeditor-add-placeholder-plugin-using-typescript-and-angular-2-0/64329399#64329399

Answer (score 5):

ng-ckeditor uses the CKEditor CDN. [This page](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/) shows you how to add external plugins either from the cdn or downloading the plugin and using a local version.

```
declare var CKEDITOR: any;

CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal(
  'uploadimage',
  '../full-all/plugins/divarea/',
  'plugin.js');
```

This is accessing the full-all path on the cdn. alternatively if you want to access it from a local folder you would make the path something like /users/app/assets/...etc depending on where your downloaded folder is located.

In your html you'd add the following: `[config]="{extraPlugins: 'divarea'}"`
to your ckeditor tag.

Since most Angular2 use cases need the divarea plugin by default due to crash issues, any other plugins you add need to be inserted as a comma-separated string:

`[config]="{extraPlugins: 'divarea,uploadimage'}"`

If binding to a local component variable, for example, it would be like this:

```
this.ckConfig = {
  height: '250',
  extraPlugins: 'divarea,uploadimage',
  enterMode: '2',
  toolbar: [
    {name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-']},
    {name: 'clipboard', items: ['Undo', 'Redo']},
    {name: 'paragraph', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight']},
    {name: 'insert', items: ['Image']},
    {name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-']},
    {name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize']},
    {name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor' ]},
  ]
};
```

NOTE - do not leave a space after the comma. In fact NO spaces in that string, it has to be `'pluginname,pluginname,pluginname'` ...etc...

Comment: The path to my plugin is correct, yes its not found, any dea why: Resource name "cta_manager" was not found at "/../../../ckeditor/plugins/cta_manager/plugin.js?t=I3I8". also not sure why ?t=I3I8 is added at the end. Any Idia?