# CKEditor mentions using Angular 5

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I have been working on Angular 5 Project. In this Project there is requirement to use CKEditor. I have integrated CKEditor successfully. Now I have requirement to use @mentions plugin.

I have added code for mention plugin plugin

```
   <ckeditor [(ngModel)]="textdata"
                              #myckeditor="ngModel"
                              name="myckeditor"
                              required                                  
                              [config]="ckeConfig"
                              debounce="500">
                    </ckeditor>
```

> this.myckeditor.valueAccessor.instance.config.extraPlugins = "mentions";

but when I am running this application I am getting an Error.[image]

How can I resolve this error and get plugin reference?

Comment: Please share angular part where u r using angular-ckeditor directory

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446203/how-to-add-plugins-to-ng2-ckeditor-using-typescript-and-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

The message which you can see, means that plugin code is not physically present under the path CKEditor expects (there is no such file).  While there is a way to download the plugin and enable it as a local one (please see [Enabling Local Plugins](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/) section), it won’t work in this case. Your problem is different and much simpler.

You are using CDN full-all version 4.9.2 while Mentions plugins has been first introduced in version 4.10.0. **The solution is to upgrade your CDN to latest version 4.10.1**.

Please note that you should always be using the latest software version as it contains latest features and fixes for those features. If you have a look at https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.1/full-all/CHANGES.md you will see there were some fixes made in 4.10.1 to the autocomplete plugin which is a dependency of the mentions plugin.