# How to install CKEditor 4 plugin to angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am using Angular 8 framework with CKeditor to build my application.

I have installed the Ckeditor angular module, it works fine.

However, it does not show the font colour button.

According to the [web page](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/Color-toolbar-not-showing-CKEditor-4), I need to install both the Color button and Panel Button plugin to make it works.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to install these plugins. Would you tell me how to do so?

PS: Here is my "config" variable:

```
this.config.toolbarGroups = [
              { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
              { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
              { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
              { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
              { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
              { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
              { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
              { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
              { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
              { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
              { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
              { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
              { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
            ];
            this.config.removeButtons = 'Forms,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Link,Unlink,Styles,About,HorizontalRule,Blockquote,Italic,SpecialChar,Format,Outdent,NumberedList,Indent,BulletedList,RemoveFormat,Bold,PasteFromWord';
            this.config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The easiest way is to:

introduce `full.js` at `index.html`.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.15.0/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

[please look this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208766/ng2-ckeditor-add-placeholder-plugin-using-typescript-and-angular-2-0/64329399#64329399)